# how to hide cursor in XCB?

Tags: c++, c, x11, xlib, xcb

I want to hide system cursor in Xorg

I use xcb to write X11-app for Xorg, it will hide cursor in some cases (like "xbanish" or "unclutter"). I've tried use Xfixes: it works fine with xlib, but doesn't work with xcb.

My code for xlib, which hides cursor:

```c
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/extensions/Xfixes.h>

Display *conn = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
XFixesHideCursor(conn, DefaultRootWindow(conn));
Xflush(conn);
```

My code for xcb, which does nothing:

```c
#include <xcb/xcb.h>
#include <xcb/xfixes.h>

xcb_connection_t *conn = xcb_connect(NULL, NULL);
xcb_screen_t *screen = xcb_setup_roots_iterator(xcb_get_setup(conn)).data;
xcb_xfixes_hide_cursor(conn, screen->root);
xcb_flush(conn);
```

I want to understand why code for xcb doesn't do anything, or just hide cursor in xcb.

UPD

xtrace have gave me nothing, it doesn't see errors.
But I am sure, that there is an error in `xcb_xfixes_hide_cursor`, because this code give me non-NULL `generic_error`:

```c
xcb_void_cookie_t cookie = xcb_xfixes_hide_cursor_checked(conn, screen->root);
xcb_generic_error_t *generic_error = xcb_request_check(conn, cookie);
```

Actually, it gives me this error:

```
{
  "error_code": 1,
  "major_code": 138,
  "minor_code": 29,
  "sequence:": 2,
  "full_sequence": 2
}
```

I use `xcb_errors_get_name_for_minor_code` and `xcb_errors_get_name_for_major_code` from xcb-util-errors to know anything about error. It arise inside `xcb_xfixes_hide_cursor_checked`.

Comment: What does `x11trace` show with the xcb version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Actually, it gives me this error:
>
> {
>     "error_code": 1,
>     "major_code": 138,
>     "minor_code": 29,
>     "sequence:": 2,
>     "full_sequence": 2
>   }

Error 1 is `BadRequest` / `XCB_REQUEST`. You get a `BadRequest` error, because you did not initialise the XFIXES extension (= informed the X11 server about your supported version).

Relevant code in the server that checks if the request is valid for the version that the client provided:
https://codesearch.debian.net/show?file=xorg-server_2%3A1.20.4-1%2Fxfixes%2Fxfixes.c&line=150#L150

From the protocol specification (https://codesearch.debian.net/show?file=xorg-server_2%3A1.20.4-1%2Fxfixes%2Fxfixes.c&line=150#L150):

```
4. Extension initialization

The client must negotiate the version of the extension before executing
extension requests.  Behavior of the server is undefined otherwise.

QueryVersion
[...]
```

Thus, to answer your question: You need to do `xcb_xfixes_query_version(c, 4, 0)` before you can do `HideCursor` requests.

To answer your first follow-up question: Version 4.0 is the version that introduced `HideCursor`. This can be seen in the protocol specification, because `HideCursor` is documented under "XFIXES VERSION 4 OR BETTER".

To answer your second follow-up question: `XFixesHideCursor` automatically queries the version for you: https://codesearch.debian.net/show?file=libxfixes_1%3A5.0.3-1%2Fsrc%2FCursor.c&line=255#L250

This code ends up calling `XFixesHideCursor` -> `XFixesFindDisplay` -> `XFixesExtAddDisplay` and this function queries the version: https://codesearch.debian.net/show?file=libxfixes_1%3A5.0.3-1%2Fsrc%2FXfixes.c&line=79#L79

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, the easiest way to hide the cursor is to change it to an empty cursor.

```
xcb_void_cookie_t
xcb_create_glyph_cursor (xcb_connection_t *connection,
                         xcb_cursor_t      cursorId,
                         xcb_font_t        source_font, /* font for the source glyph */
                         xcb_font_t        mask_font,   /* font for the mask glyph or XCB_NONE */
                         uint16_t          source_char, /* character glyph for the source */
                         uint16_t          mask_char,   /* character glyph for the mask */
                         uint16_t          fore_red,    /* red value for the foreground of the source */
                         uint16_t          fore_green,  /* green value for the foreground of the source */
                         uint16_t          fore_blue,   /* blue value for the foreground of the source */
                         uint16_t          back_red,    /* red value for the background of the source */
                         uint16_t          back_green,  /* green value for the background of the source */
                         uint16_t          back_blue ); /* blue value for the background of the source */
```

We should be able to pass `' '` for source_char and mask_char. However, we need to pass a normal font rather than the cursor font for this to work.

I found the older idea of showing and hiding cursors to be somewhat problematic. As far as I can tell, the API is somewhat touchy with modern window managers.